# Reading 16-bit grayscale png using chunky_png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, png

I'm trying to use chunky_png for reading PNG image in Ruby on Rails. the library seems to work fine reading 8-bit PNG image. However, what I actually have is 16-bit grayscale PNG image and I want to retriev pixel brightness value of certain points. All of my attempts on retrieving pixel value always end-up with 8-bit rgba format.

Is there any way to read 16-bit brightness value from grayscale png image using chunky_png? Or should I give up and use some other tools that can do this job instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how ChunkyPNG stores color values internally, it doesn't support more than 8 bit colors per channel. It automatically converts channels to 8 bit values when it encounters higher values.

So, this is impossible now, and would require some significant rewrites of the codebase to make this possible (but pull requests are accepted! :)

Comment: Oh, so I hit the wall then. Still, many thanks. I'll definitely look into it. BTW you're the gem author, right?

Comment: Yup, wvanbergen on github = wvanbergen on StackOverflow :)